# Probit "Postestimation", in Stata: How do i specify/utilize results of my probit "Classification tables ("estat classification" command)?

Tags: classification, stata, probit, sensitivity-specificity

Is there a way or a specific command I can use in Stata for more insights and information after i Run the "estat classification" command and classification Tables for my probit model?

I know how to interpret the "sensitivity and specificity" results obtained from my estat classification command, But:

How or What additional Command in Stata  helps me further specify which are the variables that were among the correctly (or falsely) predicted by my model?

Note:
I read something about perhaps "Residuals" can help ..? But I never worked with residuals before so not sure how to get them, or how-to interpret them in the model with a probit regression anyway.

Thank you very much,
Ruba

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.